# More efficient sql to find records not in join table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have:

```
_sms_users_
id

_join_smsuser_campaigns_
sms_user_id
```

I'd like to pull out the sms_users that don't have a record in the join_smsuser_campaigns table (via the join_smsuser_campaigns.sms_user_id = sms_users.id relationships)

I have the sql:

```
select * from sms_users where id not in (select sms_user_id from join_smsuser_campaigns);
```

edit:

here's the explain select results:

```
mysql> explain select u.* from sms_users u left join join_smsuser_campaigns c on u.id = c.sms_user_id  where c.sms_user_id is null;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key                                                         | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | ALL   | NULL          | NULL                                                        | NULL    | NULL | 42303 |                                      |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | index | NULL          | index_join_smsuser_campaigns_on_campaign_id_and_sms_user_id | 8       | NULL | 30722 | Using where; Using index; Not exists |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------------+

mysql> describe sms_users;
+------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                     | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |

mysql> describe join_smsuser_campaigns;
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sms_user_id         | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
```

Looks like the problm is that I don't have an index on sms_user_id on the join?

This takes about 5 minutes to run and I see that there is one record. Is there a more efficient way to do this via a join? My sql skills are pretty basic.

Comment: Your query should be fine, assuming you have an index on `join_smsuser_campaigns(sms_user_id)`.

Comment: After adding the index both queries (the original and the new) are in a fraction of a second. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries can get slow when having many items in the `IN` clause. Use a `left join` instead

```
select u.*
from sms_users u
left join join_smsuser_campaigns c on u.id = c.sms_user_id 
where c.sms_user_id is null
```

See [this great join explanation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: thanks. running the query now to see if it's any faster. that link you sent is great.

Comment: It should take only milliseconds. Run `explain select ...` to see where the query does not use indexes

Comment: ok, I added an edit above with those results and the table description. I think i'm missing an index.

Comment: Yes, try adding a key to `sms_user_id`: `ALTER TABLE join_smsuser_campaigns ADD INDEX idx_sms_user_id (sms_user_id)`

Comment: See above - yes, the main issue was a missing index, but I did change the query to use the left join.